# Import Non English data from SQL Server to R

Tags: r, sql-server, dataframe, rodbc

Trying to import non English text from SQL Server to R

I am using `RODBC` Package for import the data

`library(RODBC)`
`dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=10.100.100.100;database=DB1;trusted_connection=true')`

`DF1 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from [DB1].[dbo].[DB1_Table1]',stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
odbcClose(dbhandle)`

when I import from SQL Server using above code I am getting data where ever its alphabets other than alphabets are turning into `??????????`

If I import the same data from Excel I am getting as it is Excel

Its not only Chinese char, I also have data from different language where alphabets are not used

Adding `utf-8` to query should fix it I think, but not sure where to add it

[image]

Comment: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)"

Comment: What OS do you use? Also, can you show the output of `Sys.getlocale()`

Comment: @Rohit  Using windows 10
 `[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_India.1252"`

If import the same data from Excel to R I am getting the correct data

Comment: I think you need to check the connection character set. In MySQL you would do `SET CHARACTER SET UTF8`. I'm not sure what the sql server equivalent is.